# cannot install choroplethr package on Ubuntu 13.10, error says: "rm: cannot remove 'a.out.dSYM': Is a directory"

Tags: r, install.packages, choroplethr

I am attempting to install the `choroplethr` package in R.

```
> install.packages("choroplethr")
Installing package into ‘/home/matt/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’
* installing *source* package ‘XML’ ...
** package ‘XML’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... 
rm: cannot remove 'a.out.dSYM': Is a directory
a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for sed... /bin/sed
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for xml2-config... no
Cannot find xml2-config
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘XML’
* removing ‘/home/matt/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/XML’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘XML’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘XML’ is not available for package ‘acs’
* removing ‘/home/matt/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/acs’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘acs’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘acs’ is not available for package ‘choroplethr’
* removing ‘/home/matt/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/choroplethr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘choroplethr’ had non-zero exit status
```

So, what I'm seeing is a variety of errors, the first of which is:

`rm: cannot remove 'a.out.dSYM': Is a directory`

To further add to the difficulty, the `acs` and `XML` packages fail to install as well.

Has anyone run into this problem in the past, and if so, has anyone found a solution?  How can I fix the error with the directory?

PS:  I have attempted to solve some of this by installing:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

with no change in my problems.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi Matt.  A similar issue was reported on the choroplethr mailing list, and it looks like it was solved there: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/choroplethr/XML/choroplethr/5z79lukhYOQ/HsNoPY3WFBIJ. Can you try that solution and report back to us whether that worked?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, @Ari! I'll check into it.

Comment: Using Linux Mint 17 I had the exact same issue, and it was solved by installing libxml2 and libxml2-dev as suggested in that link :)